# Compactness of the unit ball of the dual of $C(\omega_{1}+1)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, order-theory

In this [article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tkbjm/1496163163) the authors give the following example:

Let $K=\omega_1 +1$ with the order topology and $E=C(K)^{*}$ the dual of $C(K)$ equipped with the weak$^{*}$ topology.

The space $E$ can be identified with the space of all regular Borel measures on $K$. And let $C$ be the subspace of $E$ consisting of probability measures.

The space $C$ is compact.

I know that $ K $ is compact, but not metrizable, so how can I show that $ C $ is compact?

Comment: First, asking whether $E$ is compact makes no sense until you say what topology you're talking about. In the weak* topology $E$ is not compact, but $C$ is compact; no doubt that was a typo.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Comment: The authors are assuming you know the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, which says precisely that $C$ is weak* compact.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Strictly speaking, Banach-Alaoglu says that the unit ball of $E$ is weak-* compact.  It remains to show that $C$ is a weak-* closed subset of the unit ball, but that is not too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C(K)$ is a Banach space (in the sup norm) and $E$, its dual, is the space of regular Borel measures on $K$ (what I know as the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), in one of its forms). It can be given the weak$^\ast$ topology, as all duals spaces, and a standard result, the [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem) tells us that the unit ball $B$ in $E$ (in this case all measures with norm $\le 1$) is compact in that topology.

And the (regular Borel) probability measures $C$ (having norm $1$) are a closed (and hence compact) subspace of that compact ball $B$. So it's all based on standard results (provided you did a reasonably advanced course in (standard) Banach spaces).